# Task, await and ManagementObjectCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, lambda, async-await

I am trying to discover all the Logical Disk connected to a system using a Lambda expression using the await keyword to execute the function asynchronously. Everything seems to be fine except for the return statment.

`return(Search.Get());` does not compile, due to this error:

> "Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type (CS1662) - D:\PugApplications\Pug_AdvancedControls\Pug_AdvancedControls\Pug_FileSystemTree\Pug_FileSystemNode.cs:34,14

How can I do this? Everything I've read indicates that this should work.

Pug_DriveType is just a enumeration that I wrote to mirror the Win32 DriveType enumeration.

// Read Drives

```
Func<Pug_DriveType, Task<ManagementObjectCollection>> ReadTask = (Pug_DriveType DT) =>
{

    StringBuilder Query =
        new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=\"")
        .Append((int)DT).Append("\"");

    ManagementObjectSearcher Search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Query.ToString());

    return (Search.Get());
};
```

Thanks for any help
Danny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
Func<Pug_DriveType, Task<ManagementObjectCollection>> ReadTask = async (Pug_DriveType DT) =>
{

    StringBuilder Query =
        new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=\"")
        .Append((int)DT).Append("\"");

    ManagementObjectSearcher Search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Query.ToString());

    return await Task.Run(() => Search.Get());
};
```

Or possibly:

```
Func<Pug_DriveType, Task<ManagementObjectCollection>> ReadTask = (Pug_DriveType DT) =>
{

    StringBuilder Query =
        new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=\"")
        .Append((int)DT).Append("\"");

    ManagementObjectSearcher Search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Query.ToString());

    return Task.Run(() => Search.Get());
};
```

(Depending on what else you might wind up putting in the anonymous method there.)

Either of the above causes your anonymous method to return the `Task<ManagementObjectCollection>`, the return type for the declared delegate type variable to which the delegate instance is assigned. The error you got was telling you that the lambda expression was returning a type different than the one for the delegate type inferred (based on the variable's type) for the expression.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for the response. Under the lambda expression I am executing Results = await ReadTask(DType); for each Drive Type and then add the result to a TreeView. I don't see how your answer will help. Can you add more explanation. Thankyou

Comment: Peter I just triesd your two examples and both fail to compile return a "All code paths fail to return value" error. Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry...typo. Left out the actual `return` keyword.

Comment: Yep it works now Peter. Thanks all good. I should have picked up on that myself.

Comment: I also added an explanation that I hope makes clearer why these versions of the lambda work when the original one didn't. Hope that helps!